# Generating workspace id

Tags: python, chatbot, watson-conversation

I am currently working on IBM Watson python sdk.
And I have used the following code:

```
context = {}

workspace_id = '25dfa8a0-0263-471b-8980-317e68c30488'

response = conversation.message(
   workspace_id=workspace_id,
   message_input={'text': 'Turn on the lights'},
   context=context
)

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

But this id is not valid for me. Anyone know how i can generate one for myself

Comment: It's look like you are working associated with an API, So there should be a mechanism to generate your own key.

Answer (score 1):

You do not generate the `workspace_id` yourself. `workspace_id` is a unique key identifying the workspace you want to communicate via the api. The id is generated when you create a new workspace within the Watson Conversation UI.

Comment: thanx but how can I create a new workspace in Python?